# All images are loading at once angular material

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lazy-loading, angular-material

I am using [me-lazyload](https://github.com/Treri/me-lazyload) and copy paste exact code and placed in my controllers and views no error is showing and all images are loading at once not on scrolling .. I am using angular material.

```
var url = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6ca6c6611136a3e05ce30d872da1b551.jpg?s=100';
var ary = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < 40; i++){
     ary.push(url + '&t=' + i + (+new Date()))
   }
 $scope.images = ary;


<div class="container">
    <div class="wrap" ng-repeat="img in images">
        <img lazy-src="{{img}}" alt="">
    </div>
</div>

angular
        .module('app', [
            'ui.router',
            'triangular',
            'ngAnimate',
            'ngMaterial',
            'angularGrid',
            'ya.nouislider',
            'ngTouch',
            'sap.imageloader',
            'me-lazyload'
        ])
```

Plunker Link : https://plnkr.co/edit/5co6RSjJkkxdipaHPFAF?p=preview

I have also implement [angular lazy img](https://github.com/Pentiado/angular-lazy-img) but same behavior Images are loading at once.

Is this a issue with angular material contents or I am doing something wrong ?

Comment: Did you import the module as shown in the documentation? `var app = angular.module('myApp', ['me-lazyload'])`

Comment: yeah man I added :)

Comment: Could you show us that code?

Comment: I update my question you can check now.

Comment: check this 
http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6ca6c6611136a3e05ce30d872da1b551.jpg?s=100&t=01496150047806

Comment: it would be easier for us to resolve the issue if you could create a plunkr reflecting issue

Comment: @the_mishra, I added plunker link in my question please have a look.

Comment: @QubaishBhatti I have checked your plunkr, if you will include CSS which is in example.html on GitHub, then its working fine!!